# How to put for Multiple users each users take unique value for each iteration in Csvfile using python

Tags: python, csv, performance-testing, load-testing, locust

I have to take unique value for each users in csv for each iteration.
Will you prefer any suggestions it would be better for my next process...

Comment: It is really unclear what you are asking. Can you please try to make it more concise/clear and possibly include an example?

Comment: I have to take different value from each user for example. In CSV  Account name prabha1, prabha2 ,. 2 users have to take unique values not same value

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
from locust import HttpLocust, TaskSet, task
import logging, sys
import csv

USER_CREDENTIALS = None

class LoginWithUniqueUsersSteps(TaskSet):
    email = "NOT_FOUND"
    password = "NOT_FOUND"

    def on_start(self):
            if len(USER_CREDENTIALS) > 0:
                self.email, self.password = USER_CREDENTIALS.pop()

    @task
    def login(self):
        self.client.post("/login", {
            'email': self.email, 'password': self.password
        })
        logging.info('Login with %s email and %s password', self.email, self.password)

class LoginWithUniqueUsersTest(HttpLocust):
    task_set = LoginWithUniqueUsersSteps
    host = "http://blazedemo.com"
    sock = None

    def __init__(self):
        super(LoginWithUniqueUsersTest, self).__init__()
        global USER_CREDENTIALS
        if (USER_CREDENTIALS == None):
            with open('credentials.csv', 'rb') as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f)
                USER_CREDENTIALS = list(reader)
```

should do the trick for you.

More information:

- [Locust experiments — Feeding the locusts](https://medium.com/locust-io-experiments/locust-experiments-feeding-the-locusts-cf09e0f65897)
- [How to Run Locust with Different Users](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-run-locust-with-different-users)

Comment: I have to take different value from each user for example. In CSV Account name prabha1, prabha2 ,. 2 users have to take unique values not same value, if you give clear csvreader it is very helpful for me